# Run all stylecop rules in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, rules, stylecop

Is there anyway to run all StyleCop rules from a unit test (equivalent to rescan all) and assert based on warnings?

Thanks in advance!

/Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you *can* do it, but it is very (!) unusual way of using StyleCop.

First, you should learn how to run StyleCop from the code. This discussion contains some examples that can help implementing this: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/220546.

Then, you will be able to create unit-test that will enumerate and check all source files in specified location. The bad part here is that you will need to specify this location somehow, and unit-test will work with source codes instead of compiled assembly (which is rather untypical).

But anyway, I would recommend reconsidering your approach. It is not really required to consider StyleCop error as compilation errors. You could perform analysis on build-server and share the results in any way you like (the same thing about unit-tests) - everything in your hands!

Comment: I agree that StyleCop errors shoulsn't be treated as compilation errors. However I would like to see it merged with our CI somehow and provide some kind of feedback to the developer. Devs, including myself, will almost never look at the attached artifacts manually. The same is the case for code coverage, performance test etc. We need feedback. Getting the stylecop analysis into a unittest, would provide the feedback out of the box. I do however acknowledge that it might not be the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Conclusion so far, is to integrate StyleCop warnings in an artifact for TeamCity. Maybe develope an e-mail notification or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just include it in my build-process and treat a build as failed if there're warnings (via a nant or ant return code or something similar). You can configure these tools to only spit out the warnings you want.

Why do you need it in a Unit-Test anyway?

Comment: There's a big difference between treating each static code analysis rule as an error at compile time and in unit test. In the beginning of a task, it will be very invasive, if each and little stylecop rule will generate an error - e.g. double spaces, missing comments etc. We have a check-in-dance, which include the StyleCop step, but many neglect this step (it's an manually step - I understand why!). If we included the static code analysis in a unittest, it will either be captured by the mandatory run of unittests before checkin or by our CI.

Comment: Imho that will just bloat Unit-Tests. Take a day and adjust the rules, then integrate it in your build cycle. You can also flag the warnings as irrelevant if you don't want them to produce an error.